# How to do OnClick on selected item in "dynamic" ASP.NET DropDownList without using JavaScript

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu, onclick

Currently, there is 2 values in my DropDownList which is viewProduct and editProduct. So when the user selects one of the value, it will direct user to the particular function in ASP.NET. I have tried OnSelectedIndexChanged, but it seems like not working on the dynamic DropDownList.
Here is my code:

```
            ddlAction.ID = "ddlForAction";
            ddlAction.CssClass = "ddlList";
            ddlAction.CausesValidation = false;
            ddlAction.AutoPostBack = true;
            ddlAction.Items.Add(new ListItem("View","viewProduct"));
            ddlAction.Items.Add(new ListItem("Edit", "editProduct"));
            e.Row.Cells[5].Controls.Add(ddlAction);
      
            if(ddlAction.SelectedValue == "editProduct")
            {
                editProduct();
            }
            else if(ddlAction.SelectedValue == "viewProduct")
            {
                retrieveProduct();
            }
```

Any idea how to solve it **without** using JavaScript?
My entire code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindGridView();
    }

    private void BindGridView()
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(sqlConn);
        string sql = "SELECT prodID, prodName, stockLevel, reorderLevel, unitPrice from Product";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
        MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        productList.DataSource = dt;
        productList.DataBind();
    }

    protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        TableCell tc = new TableCell();
        DropDownList ddlAction = new DropDownList();
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "Prod ID";
            e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "Product Name";
            e.Row.Cells[2].Text = "Qty";
            e.Row.Cells[3].Text = "Reorder Level";
            e.Row.Cells[4].Text = "Price (RM)";
            e.Row.Controls.Add(tc);
        }
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            var qty = Int16.Parse(e.Row.Cells[2].Text);
            var reorder = Int16.Parse(e.Row.Cells[3].Text);
            if (qty <= reorder)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[2].CssClass = "redCell";
                e.Row.Cells[3].CssClass = "redCell";
            }
            e.Row.Controls.Add(tc);
            ddlAction.ID = "ddlForAction";
            ddlAction.CssClass = "ddlList";
            ddlAction.CausesValidation = false;
            ddlAction.AutoPostBack = true;
            ddlAction.Items.Add(new ListItem("View","viewProduct"));
            ddlAction.Items.Add(new ListItem("Edit", "editProduct"));
            e.Row.Cells[5].Controls.Add(ddlAction);
            ddlAction.SelectedIndexChanged += DDLAction_OnSelectedIndexChanged;

            if (ddlAction.SelectedValue == "editProduct")
            {
                editProduct();
            }
            else if (ddlAction.SelectedValue == "viewProduct")
            {
                retrieveProduct();
            }


        }
     }
```

Comment: There is no event handler assigned to your `DropDownList`, you must assign an event handler to work probably.

Comment: yes, I have assigned an event handler on the`aspx.cs` as I am using **dynamic** `DropDownList`. But I could not get the ID of my `ddlAction`. Even I manually add the Event Handler on the `aspx.cs.desginer` side, it still unable to work.

Comment: If you're trying to get the Id from javascript, you need to use `ddlForAction.ClientId` which is simply the contentId plus the control id similar to `MainContent_ddlForAction`. as the control ids are dynamic in ASP.NET unless you specified `ClientMode = static` to the control, then it'll be static id `ddlForAction`.

Comment: Hmm.. because I’m not using JavaScript, can you provide some example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare an event handler then assign it to the control before adding the control to the page.

Here is an example :

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        CreateControl();
    }
}

protected void CreateControl()
{
    var ddlAction = new DropDownList();
    ddlAction.ID = "ddlForAction";
    ddlAction.CssClass = "ddlList";
    ddlAction.CausesValidation = false;
    ddlAction.AutoPostBack = true;
    ddlAction.Items.Add(new ListItem("View","viewProduct"));
    ddlAction.Items.Add(new ListItem("Edit", "editProduct"));
    ddlAction.SelectedIndexChanged += DDLAction_OnSelectedIndexChanged;
    e.Row.Cells[5].Controls.Add(ddlAction);
}

protected void DDLAction_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var action = (DropDownList) sender;

    var choice = action.SelectedValue?.Trim();
    
    string script = null;

    switch (choice)
    {
        case "viewProduct":
            script = "alert('View page!');";
            break;
        case "editProduct":
            script = "alert('Edit page!');";
            break;
        default:
            script = "alert('Unmatched Value!')";
            break;
    }
    
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this , typeof(_Default) , "TestJS" , $"<script>{script}</script>" , false);
}
```

use `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` when you want to work with JS scripts. `Response.Write` will not parse script blocks as an executable blocks. It will throw a parse error though (you could check the browser console.

Comment: Is 'ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript' able to display message only? Because I am planning to do when `SelectedValue == "editProduct"`, it will proceed to the `retrievedItem()` function, the purpose I put ` Response.Write("<script>alert('Edit page!')</script>");` is just to let me test the function. But the example you shared to me only able works on the `if (action.SelectedValue == "editProduct")` when I choosing `View`, it still displayed" Edit Page !" instead "View Page!"

Comment: @SHAOHONGLI scriptmanager executes scripts. So, if you use `retrievedItem()` it'll be executed dynamically on the page. I've updated the example to more manageable approach.

Comment: @SHAOHONGLI if you want to process all things from code behind (without JS) include your JS scripts that you use, so we can convert them to the code behind.